# Can't remove device from Ubuntu One

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I have a few devices connected to my Ubuntu One account.  From https://one.ubuntu.com/account/, I removed the device I no longer wanted connected.  It seemed to remove successfully.

However, as a test, when I deleted some files from the Ubuntu One directory from the removed device, I noticed that the file also get removed from the Ubuntu One online account and also from all the other connected devices.

So my question is.  How do I remove a device from ubuntu one?

Bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/1088855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a device from the web site does not disconnect the device if it is currently connected to the service. You'll need to "Disconnect" that device from within the control panel, and then remove the device from the web site. Or you can just click the "Remove" on the devices tab of the control panel, from the device you wish to remove, to remove it.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right.  I just tried this, and yes, it stopped syncing.  So I deleted the files in the ubuntu one directory on the disconnected device.  All good so far.  I made some changes to the ubuntu one directory from another connected device.  Then later when I decided to connect the disconnected device, it deleted everything from the cloud...  That is not right, shouldn't a disconnected device just download what is on the cloud when it is reconnected, instead of deleting everything, even if other connected devices have made changes to the cloud...

Comment: Ubuntu One will rescan and see that you deleted the files, when you reconnect the device, and then delete them on the server (and move to trash on other connected machines) as well. You would need to disconnect a device, stop all the Ubuntu One related processes, and remove the metadata, for the behavior you described. Perhaps this should be the default when removing a device, but that should be discussed in a bug report, and not on askUbuntu.